# Prevent reload/scroll to top when clicking on youtube icon into an iframe on ionic

Tags: angularjs, iframe, youtube, ionic-framework

I have a problem with showing a youtube video through an `iframe`.

When I click on the youtube icon, the page is being reloaded OR the page scrolls to the top. The page scroll only when the `iframe` is not on top of the page, but for example under a list or after some element.

How do you prevent the page to reload or scroll to the top after clicking on the youtube icon?

If I move the `iframe` to the top, the reload and scrolling isn't occurring. When the `iframe` isn't on top of the page, the page reloads or scrolls to the top.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why iframes do this but I found if, before adding in the iframe, save the body's scrollTop property in a variable and then, after the iframe is added, set the body's scollTop to that variable. The trick is to reassign the value in a setTimeout function. See the following:

```
var scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
element.appendChild(iframe);
setTimeout(function() {
    document.body.scrollTop = scrollTop;
});
```

Comment: Seems a bit hacky but it works with no noticeable detriment to the user experience.